# How can I rewrite this BASH for loop not using the `seq` command?

Tags: bash

I was trying to write a BASH loop of the form:

```
~/$ for i in {1..$(grep -c "match" file)} ; do echo $i ; done
{1..20}
```

where I was hoping it would produce counted output.  So I tried this instead:

```
~/$ export LOOP_COUNT=$(grep -c "match" file)
~/$ for i in {1..$LOOP_COUNT} ; do echo $i ; done
{1..20}
```

What I fell back to using was:

```
~/$ for i in $(seq 1 1 $(grep -c "match" file)) ; do echo $i ; done
1
2
3
...
20
```

Perfect! *But how can I get that behaviour without using* `seq`?

Comment: What's wrong with `seq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
max=$(grep -c "match" file)

for (( c=1; c <= $max; c++ ))
do
    echo $c
done
```

Comment: +1, however this is only supported in newer versions of BASH.

Comment: That works, I forgot about that construct.  I guess I was really wondering if the {n..m} construct does what I wanted it too.

Comment: Be careful though, it is a bash specific feature. Personally i like my script beeing able to run in /bin/sh even if a use Linux and OS X with fairly new versions of bash.

Comment: @Mithrandir if you're concerned about portability, `{1..n}` is a bash-specific feature as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to bash documentation

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
>   either integers or single characters, and incr, an  optional 
>   increment, is  an  integer.

You can still use `eval` in other cases, but Mithrandir's advice is probably faster.

```
eval "for i in {1..$(grep -c 'match' file)} ; do echo \$i ; done"
```

Comment: That answers the question I wanted to ask.  Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
loop () {
    i=$1
    n=$2 
    echo $i
    ((i < n)) && loop $((i+1)) $n
}

LOOP_COUNT=$(grep -c "Int" sum.scala)

loop 1 $LOOP_COUNT
```